# Classification Module from Capsule Network Code

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, conv-neural-network

Refer to the [Capsule Network Code](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/extra_capsnets.ipynb), I am using just the classification module from the mentioned code, So following is the complete classification code that I extracted from the link.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

np.random.seed(42)
tf.set_random_seed(42)

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/")

X = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 28, 28, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name="X")

caps1_n_maps = 32
caps1_n_caps = caps1_n_maps * 6 * 6  # 1152 primary capsules
caps1_n_dims = 8

conv1_params = {
    "filters": 256,
    "kernel_size": 9,
    "strides": 1,
    "padding": "valid",
    "activation": tf.nn.relu,
}

conv2_params = {
    "filters": caps1_n_maps * caps1_n_dims, # 256 convolutional filters
    "kernel_size": 9,
    "strides": 2,
    "padding": "valid",
    "activation": tf.nn.relu
}

conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(X, name="conv1", **conv1_params)
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, name="conv2", **conv2_params)

caps1_raw = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, caps1_n_caps, caps1_n_dims],name="caps1_raw")


def squash(s, axis=-1, epsilon=1e-7, name=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name, default_name="squash"):
        squared_norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(s), axis=axis,keep_dims=True)
        safe_norm = tf.sqrt(squared_norm + epsilon)
        squash_factor = squared_norm / (1. + squared_norm)
        unit_vector = s / safe_norm
        return squash_factor * unit_vector

caps1_output = squash(caps1_raw, name="caps1_output")

caps2_n_caps = 10
caps2_n_dims = 16

init_sigma = 0.1

W_init = tf.random_normal(
    shape=(1, caps1_n_caps, caps2_n_caps, caps2_n_dims, caps1_n_dims),
    stddev=init_sigma, dtype=tf.float32, name="W_init")
W = tf.Variable(W_init, name="W")

batch_size = tf.shape(X)[0]
W_tiled = tf.tile(W, [batch_size, 1, 1, 1, 1], name="W_tiled")

caps1_output_expanded = tf.expand_dims(caps1_output, -1,
                                       name="caps1_output_expanded")
caps1_output_tile = tf.expand_dims(caps1_output_expanded, 2,
                                   name="caps1_output_tile")
caps1_output_tiled = tf.tile(caps1_output_tile, [1, 1, caps2_n_caps, 1, 1],
                             name="caps1_output_tiled")

caps2_predicted = tf.matmul(W_tiled, caps1_output_tiled,
                            name="caps2_predicted")

raw_weights = tf.zeros([batch_size, caps1_n_caps, caps2_n_caps, 1, 1],
                       dtype=np.float32, name="raw_weights")

#ROUND 1

routing_weights = tf.nn.softmax(raw_weights, dim=2, name="routing_weights")

weighted_predictions = tf.multiply(routing_weights, caps2_predicted,
                                   name="weighted_predictions")
weighted_sum = tf.reduce_sum(weighted_predictions, axis=1, keep_dims=True,
                             name="weighted_sum")

caps2_output_round_1 = squash(weighted_sum, axis=-2,
                              name="caps2_output_round_1")


#ROUND 2
caps2_output_round_1_tiled = tf.tile(
    caps2_output_round_1, [1, caps1_n_caps, 1, 1, 1],
    name="caps2_output_round_1_tiled")

agreement = tf.matmul(caps2_predicted, caps2_output_round_1_tiled,
                      transpose_a=True, name="agreement")

raw_weights_round_2 = tf.add(raw_weights, agreement,
                             name="raw_weights_round_2")

routing_weights_round_2 = tf.nn.softmax(raw_weights_round_2,
                                        dim=2,
                                        name="routing_weights_round_2")
weighted_predictions_round_2 = tf.multiply(routing_weights_round_2,
                                           caps2_predicted,
                                           name="weighted_predictions_round_2")
weighted_sum_round_2 = tf.reduce_sum(weighted_predictions_round_2,
                                     axis=1, keep_dims=True,
                                     name="weighted_sum_round_2")
caps2_output_round_2 = squash(weighted_sum_round_2,
                              axis=-2,
                              name="caps2_output_round_2")

caps2_output = caps2_output_round_2
#ESTIMATE CLASS PROBABILITIES

def safe_norm(s, axis=-1, epsilon=1e-7, keep_dims=False, name=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name, default_name="safe_norm"):
        squared_norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(s), axis=axis,
                                     keep_dims=keep_dims)
        return tf.sqrt(squared_norm + epsilon)

y_proba = safe_norm(caps2_output, axis=-2, name="y_proba")
y_proba_argmax = tf.argmax(y_proba, axis=2, name="y_proba")

y_pred = tf.squeeze(y_proba_argmax, axis=[1,2], name="y_pred")


y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int64, name="y")

m_plus = 0.9
m_minus = 0.1
lambda_ = 0.5

T = tf.one_hot(y, depth=caps2_n_caps, name="T")

caps2_output_norm = safe_norm(caps2_output, axis=-2, keep_dims=True,
                              name="caps2_output_norm")

present_error_raw = tf.square(tf.maximum(0., m_plus - caps2_output_norm),
                              name="present_error_raw")
present_error = tf.reshape(present_error_raw, shape=(-1, 10),
                           name="present_error")

absent_error_raw = tf.square(tf.maximum(0., caps2_output_norm - m_minus),
                             name="absent_error_raw")
absent_error = tf.reshape(absent_error_raw, shape=(-1, 10),
                          name="absent_error")

L = tf.add(T * present_error, lambda_ * (1.0 - T) * absent_error,
           name="L")
margin_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(L, axis=1), name="margin_loss")


loss = tf.add(margin_loss, 0, name="loss")

correct = tf.equal(y, y_pred, name="correct")
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32), name="accuracy")

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, name="training_op")

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

n_epochs = 10
batch_size = 50
restore_checkpoint = True

n_iterations_per_epoch = mnist.train.num_examples // batch_size
n_iterations_validation = mnist.validation.num_examples // batch_size
best_loss_val = np.infty
checkpoint_path = "./my_capsule_network"

with tf.Session() as sess:
    if restore_checkpoint and tf.train.checkpoint_exists(checkpoint_path):
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)
    else:
        init.run()

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for iteration in range(1, n_iterations_per_epoch + 1):
            X_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            # Run the training operation and measure the loss:
            _, loss_train = sess.run(
                [training_op, loss],
                feed_dict={X: X_batch.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1]),
                           y: y_batch})
            print("\rIteration: {}/{} ({:.1f}%)  Loss: {:.5f}".format(
                      iteration, n_iterations_per_epoch,
                      iteration * 100 / n_iterations_per_epoch,
                      loss_train),
                  end="")

        # At the end of each epoch,
        # measure the validation loss and accuracy:
        loss_vals = []
        acc_vals = []
        for iteration in range(1, n_iterations_validation + 1):
            X_batch, y_batch = mnist.validation.next_batch(batch_size)
            loss_val, acc_val = sess.run(
                    [loss, accuracy],
                    feed_dict={X: X_batch.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1]),
                               y: y_batch})
            loss_vals.append(loss_val)
            acc_vals.append(acc_val)
            print("\rEvaluating the model: {}/{} ({:.1f}%)".format(
                      iteration, n_iterations_validation,
                      iteration * 100 / n_iterations_validation),
                  end=" " * 10)
        loss_val = np.mean(loss_vals)
        acc_val = np.mean(acc_vals)
        print("\rEpoch: {}  Val accuracy: {:.4f}%  Loss: {:.6f}{}".format(
            epoch + 1, acc_val * 100, loss_val,
            " (improved)" if loss_val < best_loss_val else ""))

        # And save the model if it improved:
        if loss_val < best_loss_val:
            save_path = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path)
            best_loss_val = loss_val



n_iterations_test = mnist.test.num_examples // batch_size

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)

    loss_tests = []
    acc_tests = []
    for iteration in range(1, n_iterations_test + 1):
        X_batch, y_batch = mnist.test.next_batch(batch_size)
        loss_test, acc_test = sess.run(
                [loss, accuracy],
                feed_dict={X: X_batch.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1]),
                           y: y_batch})
        loss_tests.append(loss_test)
        acc_tests.append(acc_test)
        print("\rEvaluating the model: {}/{} ({:.1f}%)".format(
                  iteration, n_iterations_test,
                  iteration * 100 / n_iterations_test),
              end=" " * 10)
    loss_test = np.mean(loss_tests)
    acc_test = np.mean(acc_tests)
    print("\rFinal test accuracy: {:.4f}%  Loss: {:.6f}".format(
        acc_test * 100, loss_test))
```

Since reconstruction module is not required so in the final loss function I have set loss = 0 for the reconstruction part so that optimizer only work on the classification loss.

```
loss = tf.add(margin_loss, 0, name="loss")
```

Now the classification module is working but the accuracy is pathetically low even for MNIST dataset, I got around 10% validation accuracy, Can somebody explain to me what is the problem here because on MNIST the Capsule Networks perform well in classification as discussed in [Paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/de7f/27677ae04bf1f09c223f68cea71af90be3d4.pdf)?

Regards

Comment: Does this code work when the loss is unmodifed?

Comment: yes complete code works fine, I mean with the reconstruction module  added but as I told, I am just extracting the classification part from it and classification accuracy should be at the level of state of art for MNIST and was claimed also in the paper that I mentioned below in my post.

Comment: What if you keep the original, full code and just multiply the reconstruction cost with a zero weight? I'm trying to understand whether the problem is related to an implementation issue.

Comment: Thats what I did and you can see that

Comment: The decoder is not there, right? I suggest going back to the original, full code, with the reconstruction model, and just multiplying the reconstruction cost in the final cost equation with zero. This way you'll eliminate whether it's really the missing reconstruction term that hinders training, or whether you messed something up when extracting the classification module.

Comment: I cannot do that for practical purposes because even though if it worked then it will NOT serve my purposes because adding decoder part has lot of pressure on the memory and I want to use this code for some data set that has dimensions much larger than MNIST. So I only need the classification part, Although I have tried the full code with reconstruction and it works,because that shows reconstruction loss and NOT classification loss.

Comment: you've copied the code from github or you've modified it?

Comment: I have mentioned that I have a code from a github and I modified one line of that code that I also mentioned explicity.

Comment: what if you try `loss = margin_loss
`  instead of `loss = tf.add(margin_loss, 0, name="loss")
`?